# Automatically Export iCalendar to .ics

Tags: matlab, shell, emacs, automation, icalendar

I need to automatically export an iCalendar calendar from iCal (obviously on a Mac) to the .ics files. I know I can manually do this in iCal by File->Export. I am pulling data from a shared calendar to be analyzed in MATLAB. I'll then want to use `cron` to pull the data frequently to be analyzed.

Alternatively, if someone knows where the calendar data is stored locally, then I guess I should be able to parse that file for the events/data.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

There exists probably no matlab implementation, at least matlab file exchange lists nothing. To get the calendar data into Matlab I would use a Java Library like [iCal4j](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j/wiki). You can call java libraries [directly in m code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-java-libraries-in-matlab.html).

There are also possibilities to access C, C++, dll and .Net in Matlab. To my opinion the java bridge is the simplest to use, that's why I suggested a java solution.

Answer (score 0):

The data directory is ~/Library/Calendars/[account]/[calendar]
The name of each subdirectory is the UID. Each subdirectory contains a file "info.plist":

account:

```
...
<key>Key</key>
<string>[UID]</string>
<key>Login</key>
<string>[account, i.e. mail address]</string>
```

calendar:

```
...
<key>Key</key>
<string>[UID]</string>
<key>Title</key>
<string>[Name of Calendar]</string>
```

Events are stored in "Events" subdirectory (1 .ics file for each event)